# Why is nginx running on port 8080 but not 81?

Tags: macos, nginx, macos-catalina

Based on `brew info nginx` the terminal output is telling me that `nginx` is running on port 8080 by default:

> The default port has been set in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf to
> 8080 so that nginx can run without sudo.

This is the full output:

```
$ brew info nginx
nginx: stable 1.19.0 (bottled), HEAD
HTTP(S) server and reverse proxy, and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
https://nginx.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.19.0 (25 files, 2.1MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-06-16 at 17:55:46
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/nginx.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl@1.1 ✔, pcre ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Docroot is: /usr/local/var/www

The default port has been set in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf to 8080 so that
nginx can run without sudo.

nginx will load all files in /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/.

To have launchd start nginx now and restart at login:
  brew services start nginx
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  nginx
==> Analytics
install: 33,973 (30 days), 101,534 (90 days), 407,985 (365 days)
install-on-request: 33,387 (30 days), 99,128 (90 days), 394,576 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

My Mac OS is Catalina 10.15

However, when I go to look at the `nginx.conf` in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` I do not see that the nginx port is open on 8080. I see it open on port 81:

```
server {
        listen       81;
        server_name  localhost;
    ....
    ....
```

When I go to visit `http://localhost:8080/` I get the nginx welcome message. However when I go to visit `http://localhost:81/` I get a "site can't be reached" `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

How is nginx running on port `8080` without such a specification in the `nginx.conf` file? And why is `nginx` *not* running on port `81` which the conf appears to suggest it should.

Here's the full `nginx.conf`:

```
# cat /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       81;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

    include servers/*;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to restart/reload Nginx yet? In order for the configuration change to take effect, you need to reload it.

You can use this command on Mac OSX to reload Nginx: `sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: After running your command I see this error: `nginx: [error] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Perhaps the problem is that I am starting `nginx` with `brew services start nginx` ? I installed `nginx` with brew so I figured I'd start / stop the process with the brew services command.

Comment: In that case, perhaps `brew services restart nginx` might work for you. If that gives an error relating to permissions, you might have to prefix that with `sudo`.